# How to remove duplicates from a list in only one method?

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I want to remove duplicates in the list, but append elements in the list when there are no duplicates in the existing data but only in the `extend()` method, not in the `append()` method (because I will treat an added list in the `append()` method as one distinctive datum).

```
from collections import UserList

class Ulist(UserList):
    def __init__(self, list_=[]):
         UserList.__init__(self)
         self.list_=list_

    def __add__(self, another):
        for i in another:
            if i in self:
                raise ValueError
                print("Duplicated Data!")
            else:
                return UserList.__add__(self, another)

    def append(self, another):
        if another in self:
            raise ValueError
            print("Duplicated Data!")
        else:
            return UserList.append(self, another)

    def extend(self, another):
        for x in another:
            if x in self:
                print("Duplicated Data! Erase the Duplicated Data")
                listList=UserList.extend(self, another)
                listList=list(set(listList))
                return listList
                       
            else:
                return UserList.extend(self, another)
```

And this is the error message when I work with the list having an element duplicated with the existing list. I don't understand how `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable` applies. How do I correct the `extend()` method?

```
>>> l=Ulist()
>>> l.__add__([98])
[]
>>> l.append('kim')
>>> l.extend(['lee', 'park', 'choi'])
>>> l.append(['kim', 'jeong', 'kang'])
>>> l.extend(['lee', 'kim', 'joo'])
Duplicated Data! Erase the Duplicated Data
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#110>", line 1, in <module>
    l.extend(['lee', 'kim', 'joo'])
  File "C:\Users\소현\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\User_list.py", line 28, in extend
    listList=list(set(listList))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: There is no point having a `print` statement immediately *after* `raise` - it will not be reached.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing duplicates in lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/removing-duplicates-in-lists)

Comment: Also I'm not sure what `self.list_` is for, because you never use it. But it is not advisable to have a mutable object as a function default - if it is needed at all, then have it default to `None` and conditionally set it to `[]` within the body of `__init__`.

Comment: Another issue you might have is that you default `list_` to `[]`. See this link for more info: https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#what-you-wrote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Various issues with the code:

- `self.list_` is never used (and the base class does not use it either), so just remove it. Having removed it, there is no further purpose for your `__init__`, so remove that also.  (If you did use it, then using a mutable argument as function default would also be a problem.)
- `UserList.append` and `UserList.extend` both return `None` so there is no point in explicitly returning this value in your overridden versions (it will default to returning `None` on reaching end of the function).
- You have statements after `raise` statements, which cannot be reached. Get rid of them, and you can incorporate the messages into the exception message.
- In your `extend`, you are trying to iterate over the `None` returned from `UserList.extend`, and even if the item is not already found, you have a problem that you are doing the `extend` inside a loop over items so you can end up with the whole `another` list added multiple times.
- It would also be a good idea to use `super` so that instead of `Userlist.append(self, another)` you use `super().append(another)`. This would make it easier later to change which base class you inherit from.

Here is a revised version:

```
from collections import UserList

class Ulist(UserList):

    def __add__(self, another):
        for i in another:
            if i in self:
                raise ValueError("Duplicated Data!")
            else:
                return super().__add__(another)

    def append(self, another):
        if another in self:
            raise ValueError("Duplicated Data!")
        else:
            super().append(another)

    def extend(self, another):
        for x in another:
            if x in self:
                print("Duplicated Data! Erase the Duplicated Data")
            else:
                super().append(x)
```

Or you could also change `extend` to utilise the `append` method shown here:

```
    def extend(self, another):
        for x in another:
            try:
                self.append(x)
            except ValueError as exc:
                print(exc)
```

Comment: Concerning the second point, I would say that one significant reason of subclassing is to change this behavior (to enable chaining for example)

Comment: @JanStránský Thanks, and fair enough if it actually did change this behaviour, but explicitly propagating the `None` that is returned seemed not really worth it, compared to being able to simplify the code a bit. I've changed the wording slightly so as to reflect better what I meant by it.

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is that `UserList.extend` returns nothing (`None`).
So in your code

```py
                listList=UserList.extend(self, another)
                listList=list(set(listList))
```

`listList` on the first line is `None`. Then when you pass it to `set`, you get this error (the same as `set(None)`)

Comment: Why is it so? Isn't UserList.extend(self, another) making an extended list?

Comment: @So-hyeonJung the `extend` method modifies the existing list in-place. it doesn't create a new list.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for [`set()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset).

```
items = (
    "kim",
    "lee",
    "park",
    "choi",
    "kim",
    "jeong",
    "kang",
    "lee",
    "kim",
    "joo"
)
uniques = set()
for item in items:
    uniques.add(item)
```

This will only keep the unique items you add to the *set*.

Results:

> {'choi', 'jeong', 'joo', 'kang', 'kim', 'lee', 'park'}

Comment: couple of things. 1) `uniques = set(items)` will let you skip the loop 2) the OP is already using `set`. the issue was the fact that the `List.extend` method mutates the original instead of returning a copy.

Comment: Yes, the loop is done to show that items can be added in a similar way to `.append()`.  This is an alternative solution, suggesting that this may resolve what the OP is trying to achieve in building a _list_ of items without duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

the problematic line is this one:

```
                listList=UserList.extend(self, another)
```

here it seems to me that maybe the Userlist object is not initiated properly, and thus is None type.
it is hard to tell what to do because we don't have the UserList **init**() method, but I think you might heave meant to do somthing such as:

```
def extend(self, another):
        for x in another:
            if x in self:
                print("Duplicated Data! Erase the Duplicated Data")
                listList=UserList(   ----- put args here ----     ).extend(self, another)
                listList=list(set(listList))
                return listList
```

Comment: "we don't have the UserList.__init()__ method`" - it is "normal" class from `collections` module, as shown in OP code

Comment: I have the init() method. I just knew that I missed it.

Answer (score -1):

After adding all the elements you want then use the following

```
x = list(set(x))
```

This will remove all the duplicates.

Comment: I didn't understand what you said.

Comment: OP = original poster. The example code posted already uses the `set` function.